# Tensorflow: create boolean matrix given True indices

Tags: python, tensorflow

Suppose I have below two vectors, one for start index, the other for end index

```
start_index = [1, 1, 2]
end_index = [3, 4, 3]
```

and below I have the shape of the final boolean matrix

```
shape = [3, 6]
```

I want to generate below boolean matrix

```
bool_mat = [[False, True,  True, True, False, False]
            [False, True,  True, True, True,  False]
            [False, False, True, True, False, False]]
```

for each row True starts from index in start_index and end at index in end_index, and False elsewhere,

```
bool_mat[i, start_index[i]:end_index[i]+1] = True
```

How to do this in TensorFlow? thanks!

Comment: Are the start_index and end_index lists or tensors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

start_index = tf.constant([1, 1, 2])
end_index = tf.constant([3, 4, 3])
shape = tf.constant([3, 6])
col = tf.range(shape[1])
result = (col >= start_index[:, tf.newaxis]) & (col <= end_index[:, tf.newaxis])
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(result))
```

Output:

```
[[False  True  True  True False False]
 [False  True  True  True  True False]
 [False False  True  True False False]]
```